# Android java class onClickListener

Tags: java, android, sdk, onclicklistener

How can I set an onClick listener for a button in layout_one?  Where do I put the code?  when I put it in the onCreateView it gives me an error.

```
public class LayoutOne extends Fragment {

    Button button;

    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        LayoutOne f = new LayoutOne();

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_one, null);

        return root;

    }
```

Comment: is R.layout.layout_one file is layout file of fragment?

Comment: layout_one is a layout, however it is a layout that is displayed in a ViewPager,

Answer (score 2):

set Layout attribute `android:clickable="true"`, `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` from xml or `setClickable(true)` from code. set onClickListener as:

```
((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_one_id)).setClickable(true);   ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_one_id)).setOnClickListener(layoutOnClickListener);

    private OnClickListener layoutOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //Get Click here
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

It wont give any error if You will do it something like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_one, null);
    Button button_one=(Button)root.findViewById(R.id.button_one);// button_one is the id of the button in your xml file
    button_one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    return root;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what your button is called, but in `onCreateView()` you do:

```
button = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.layout_one_id);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //stuff goes in here
    }
});
```

Your other option is to do it in xml and just make a method that uses it. For example, setting the `Button`s `android:onClick="onButtonClicked"` attribute, in code your method would look like this

```
public void onButtonClicked(View v) { /*Stuff*/ }
```